# Plot only smooth line?

Tags: r, smoothing, boxplot

I want to do a plot of just the lowess line of my boxplot. 
Is there a way to show only that line in the plot and delete the boxplot?

I have this.

```
du=boxplot(Q~Duration)
lines(lowess(du$stats[3,],f=1/5))
```

[image]

Or is there other function to show that line or type of relation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `plot()` to just plot the output of `lowess`, likely with `type="l"` to draw data as a line, so:

```
plot(lowess(du$stats[3,],f=1/5),type="l")
```